# Un-standardize feature weights

Tags: regression, standardization, weights

I have a linear regression model $y_a = \theta_a^T\tilde{f}$, where $\theta_a$ is a vector of learned feature weights and $\tilde{f}$ is my standardised feature vector;

$$
\tilde{f} = \frac{f - \mu}{\sigma}
$$

I want to compare the learned weights $\theta_a$ with another model $y_b = \theta_b^Tf$ that was trained using the raw features $f$.

How can I convert $\theta_a$ to the appropriate units to compare with the raw-feature model weights $\theta_b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some simple algebra should do the trick. The following formulation is for the two-variable equation:

$$ \hat{y} = \hat{\alpha}_\alpha + \hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}\tilde{f_1} + \hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}\tilde{f_2} $$
$$ \hat{y} = \hat{\alpha}_\alpha + \hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}\frac{f_1-\mu_1}{\sigma_1} + \hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}\frac{f_2-\mu_2}{\sigma_2} $$

Expanding terms yields an expression with the weights on the raw features $f_1$ and $f_2$:

$$\hat{y} = \hat{\alpha}_\alpha + \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}}{\sigma_1}f_1 -\frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}}{\sigma_1}\mu_1 + \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}}{\sigma_2}f_2 -\frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}}{\sigma_2}\mu_2 $$

To make it more clear you can define the following relationships:

$$\hat{\alpha}_b = \hat{\alpha}_\alpha - \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}}{\sigma_1}\mu_1 - \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}}{\sigma_2}\mu_2$$
$$\hat{\theta}_{b,1} = \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,1}}{\sigma_1}$$
$$\hat{\theta}_{b,2} = \frac{\hat{\theta}_{\alpha,2}}{\sigma_2}$$

Comment: Thanks @kanimbla :) So all I needed to do was divide by the $\sigma$ vector! ><